# SharePoint O365 missing Format Text tab

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I want to edit a page in SharePoint but I am missing the `Format Text` tab in the ribbon in this particular site. Other sites have it. How can I get this tab back when I go to `Edit Page`

This is what I get now when I go to `Edit Page`:

[image: no format text tab]

This is the `Format Text` tab I want to get back:

[image: format text tab]

Comment: Have a similar issue in our tenant as well. We tried deactivating and then activating publishing features, but it still exists. Previously, it was working correctly and opening the page in edit mode, but now we need to edit it twice. Looks like Microsoft pushed some update which is impacting this. I have currently raised a ticket with MS support and would suggest that you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the page works well before?

Please access the edit page mode though the URL as “yoursite/Pages/YourPage.aspx?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design”, check if the Format Text Tab appear.

Whether you add any web part or code to customize this page such as Content Edit Web?

If so, try to delete it and check again.