# Format Text not showing in the ribbon pane when editing page

Tags: sharepoint-online, edit

I am trying to create and modify some pages in the Sharepoint I have but when clicking the edit page button I do not get the FORMAT TEXT neither INSERT options.

I have full control access to this SP so I think the issue is not there.

Could you help me with this?

Thanks!!!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate and re-activate the publishing feature in that site, if does not work, we can directly open the page in the edit mode.

**URL to page edit mode:**

Please access the edit page mode though the URL as “yoursite/Pages/YourPage.aspx?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design”, check if the Format Text Tab appear.

Similar thread is discussed here :

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/229587/85808

Answer (score 0):

If the publishing feature is activated, try to re-active it and see if the issue remains. 
Just like Habibur said, appending to the url: your-site/Pages/YourPage.aspx?ControlMode=Edit&DisplayMode=Design is a way to try.

Similar threads here:http://mosstechnet-kk.com/missing-format-text-insert-and-edit-source-etc-options-on-sharepoint-some-pages/

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bba84acc-b27b-4983-b0b4-263e23da0f62/missing-format-text-insert-and-edit-source-etc-options-on-some-pages?forum=sharepointcustomization